# How to keep screen from turning off when my flaslight app running?

Tags: android, light, led, flashlight

Currently i am working on my first android project.

When screen off led light also off any help guys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent the screen of an android device to turn off during the execution of an Activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335908/how-to-prevent-the-screen-of-an-android-device-to-turn-off-during-the-execution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your flashlight app is running condition, Do this

> getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

Or you can do this, 
Wake Lock 
first Add this in your manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

then,

```
 final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
  mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"");    
   mWakeLock.acquire();
```

Comment: NO problem, Use this code and next time do search first on stackoverflow then submit your question