# Why won't the screen go off when my application is visible?

Tags: android

I've got an app that seems to prevent the screen from turning off when it's visible.

- I am not holding any `SCREEN_*` wakelocks anywhere in the application.
- I *am* holding `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` for short periods of time (10-20ms). For a particular run I see this wakelock held once and then released, but the screen still stays on indefinitely.
- For this test I have set the screen timeout to the shortest possible time (15 seconds) and have disabled keeping the screen on while charging.
- If I switch away from my app to anything else, the screen goes off in 15 seconds.
- I am *not* using any kind of XML in my layout resource (as [this question suggests to keep the screen on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335908/how-to-prevent-the-screen-of-an-android-device-to-turn-off-during-the-execution))
- I am also *not* calling `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);` as a different answer to the same question suggests.

What other ways could my app be preventing the screen from turning off?  This is certainly not the intended behavior!

Comment: Are you using any third-party libraries that might be affecting matters? If you comment out your partial wakelock, does that change things? Does `adb shell dumpsys power` show any signs of something else in your process holding a wakelock? Does the behavior only occur when the device is plugged in? Is the behavior consistent across multiple devices?

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, got the command to work (although it seems to fight Android Studio for who can see the device, is there a way to run `adb shell` *inside* AS?) and I *do* see a "SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK" wake lock being held, although it doesn't say by *who* just a PID which I don't recognize (not seeing it in logcat, but seems that is restricted to only my process)

Comment: "is there a way to run adb shell inside AS?" -- use the Terminal tool, docked by default towards the bottom left.  "just a PID which I don't recognize" -- `adb shell ps ...` (where `...` is the PID) should give you a package name as part of its output.

Comment: @CommonsWare `adb shell ps ...` -> `USER=system, NAME=system_server`

Comment: I can't explain that. If you have not done so already, try rebooting the device. If your process does not have a wakelock, then there should be no reason why the screen would stay on. Your symptoms -- outside of this weird `system_server` bit -- would fit if some library (e.g., ad network) was using `android:keepScreenOn="true"` or the Java equivalent. I haven't checked if that shows up in wakelocks or not (IMHO, it should).

Comment: @CommonsWare This is weird. The wake lock seemed to be held whenever onRestart+onResume were called and released when onPause+onStop were called, so I commented out everything  in Restart/Resume except the super calls.  The wake lock stopped being held.  I started adding back code one block at a time and testing to see if the wake lock was held until finally all the code was uncommented and it still isn't holding the wake lock any more!

Comment: `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`. But, I'm glad to hear that (so far) it's working!

Comment: @CommonsWare Also noticed there was a supplemental PID under "WorkSource" but by the time I noticed this there was no longer any such PID.  It also did not match my PID, but if/when this happens again I'll be sure to see what process the worksource is to try to track down what is causing this.